# run linux command asynchronously with callback in c++

Tags: c++, linux, node.js, boost, asynchronous

I am trying to write a c++ program that will run linux commands asynchronously and register a call back for the return values of the linux command. what I exactly want is to write a utility function to which I will pass two parameter one is linux command and other one is callback.

when We call this utility function, it should not block the program and continue the execution of program. but once the linux commands executed it will invoke the callback that we pass as second parameter.

I have tried c++ system() function. and have tried boost.process headers to run 
the linux commands. but they are all blocking way of calling linux calls.from c++.

I am new to to this type of async + callback register type of programming.

The program should exactly look like the one I have tried in node.js programs that I use in my node.js programs. which works very well for me the link that I follow for this is http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs

Please help me to get this done in c++. what improvements i need to do in c++ system call that run perfectly for me but is blocking. or do we have some direct facility available in C++ or boost library.

**NOTE: I am using g++ 4.3 compiler. it is not C++0x or C++11.**

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite clear what you want to do, but here's some C++11 code that I think would do the trick:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void system(const std::string& s)
{ std::cout << "Executing system with argument '" << s << "'\n"; }


// asynchronously (1) invoke cmd as system command and (2) callback.
// return future for (1) and (2) to caller
template<typename F>                            
std::future<typename std::result_of<F()>::type> 
runCmd(const std::string& cmd, F callback)      
{                                               
  auto cmdLambda = [cmd] { system(cmd); };
  auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async,
                        [cmdLambda, callback] { cmdLambda(); return callback(); });
  return fut;  
}

int main()
{
  auto fut = runCmd("ls", []{ std::cout << "Executing callback\n"; });
  fut.get();
}
```

For C++98, you could use Boost.Threads for futures and async, and you could use Boost.Bind to replace the lambdas.

This should at least get you started.

Comment: It's pretty clearly stated in **bold** that the compiler in use doesn't support C++11

Comment: Yes, but after a week with no answers, I figured something was better than nothing, and I did offer comments about how to revise the code for C++98.